# How to migrate a codebase from one svn repo to another preserving history?

Tags: svn, svnadmin, svnsync, svndumpfilter

I have a branch in a badly structured svn repo that needs to be stripped out and moved to another svn repository. (I'm trying to clean it up some).

If I do an `svn log` and not *stop on copy/rename* I can see all 3427 commits that I care about. Is there some way to dump the revisions out, short of writing some major scripts?

I would follow the advice in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417726/how-to-move-a-single-folder-from-one-subversion-repository-to-another-repository) but this branch has been moved all over the place and I would like to preserve the moves as well.

Comment: I've asked similar questions and `svndumpfilter` always was the standard answer. Are you sure it's not going to cut it for you?

Comment: Well I could use svndumpfilter, but I think I'll have to do do at least 9 path renames at points in the dump. I just didnt know if there was an automated solution. (The repo is too messed up to use git-svn).

Comment: Why not import the revisions as-is, and rename them in subversion? There's no need to rewrite history?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess this might be similar to what @ZacThompson (and @Pekka) mean: I think `svndumpfilter` is your friend.

From your question I think you have the idea what it is meant to do but struggle with the copying/moving of the branch all over the place? An answer to that can be found in the before mentioned [SVN Documentation](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.reposadmin.maint.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.migrate), I believe:

> Also, copied paths can give you some
>   trouble. Subversion supports copy
>   operations in the repository, where a
>   new path is created by copying some
>   already existing path. It is possible
>   that at some point in the lifetime of
>   your repository, you might have copied
>   a file or directory from some location
>   that svndumpfilter  is excluding, to a
>   location that it is including. To make
>   the dump data self-sufficient,
>   svndumpfilter needs to still show the
>   addition of the new path—including the
>   contents of any files created by the
>   copy—and not represent that addition
>   as a copy from a source that won't
>   exist in your filtered dump data
>   stream. But because the Subversion
>   repository dump format shows only what
>   was changed in each revision, the
>   contents of the copy source might not
>   be readily available. If you suspect
>   that you have any copies of this sort
>   in your repository, you might want to
>   rethink your set of included/excluded
>   paths, perhaps including the paths
>   that served as sources of your
>   troublesome copy operations, too.

Meaning: make `svndumpfilter` include **all** paths the branch ever lived at. Or am I missing something?

Another possibility might be the `svndumpfilter2` mentioned by @compie in the thread you linked although I believe it is not even necessary (and I don't know either of @compie or `svndumpfilter2`).

Comment: I didn't know about svndumpfilter2 but it seems to be what I'm looking for. I'm going to try it and see how it works out.

Comment: I haven't finished my migration effort yet (huge repo 30k+ commits) but this method looks promising.

Answer (score 1):

You will want to use some combination of:

1. svnadmin dump
2. svndumpfilter
3. svnadmin load

If you want to do the whole branch, you may not even need svndumpfilter.  But if you do:

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.reposadmin.maint.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.filtering

Answer (score 0):

There is another solution that is pretty simple and solves the **"preserve the moves"** issue. Please see the last paragraph of the Apache Subversion FAQ entry ["How do I completely remove a file from the repository's history?"](http://subversion.apache.org/faq.html#removal). The solution does not rely on the `svndumpfilter`.

You can perform the following steps:

1. Configure [path-based authorization](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.serverconfig.pathbasedauthz.html) rules to **deny** read access for a *USERNAME* account to the **PATHS** of the file or a folder you want to remove from repository history.

   Please note the plural noun **paths**. The file or folder you want to get rid of could have different names or can be located in different places across a repository history. Please consider this when setting up deny rules.
2. Create an empty repository,
3. Replicate the source repository with [`svnsync`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svnsync.html) tool to the target repository under account *USERNAME*. For details on repository synchronization with `svnsync` please refer to SVNBook chapter ["Repository Replication"](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.reposadmin.maint.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.replication).

Unlike `svndumpfilter`, `svnsync` automatically translates `svn copy` operations with an unreadable source path into normal additions, which is useful if history involves copy operations and still needs to be filtered. :)

Answer (score -2):

You need to use HotCopy to backup the repository directory.  Then it should be a matter of simply restoring the repository.

Comment: I think he's talking about stripping a very complex structure (with several moves inside it) from a repo that contains a lot more.

Comment: You can't use hotcopy for this, that can only be used to make full copies of repositories