# how to migrate local svn repo to google code's svn repo?

Tags: svn, svnadmin, google-code, svndump

My issue is quite different from other posts on stackoverflow, such as [How to migrate a codebase from one svn repo to another preserving history?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2540689/how-to-migrate-a-codebase-from-one-svn-repo-to-another-preserving-history).

It is easy to migrate an svn repo from one pc to the other, since I have full control of these pcs. What should I do if I want to migrate a local svn repo to google code's svn repo?

Seems svnadmin dump and load can only be used to local URI.

So is there any other method that I can use to import a local svn dump to google's svn host?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a tool called [svnsync](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svnsync.html) which should do what you want - it essentially reads every revision from the source repo, then plays them back to the destination repo.

Be careful if you're planning to mirror between two repos, as things can get a bit out of hand; however, for a one-off migration, svnsync is probably the most straightforward option.