# problems moving a directory from one SVN repository to another

Tags: svn

I'm trying to move a directory (trunk/project/subproject) from a repository rep_a to a newly created repository rep_b

Following the instructions I've seen in [ttp://stackoverflow.com/questions/417726/...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417726/how-to-move-a-single-folder-from-one-subversion-repository-to-another-repository),

I did this:

```
svnadmin dump my_repositories/rep_a > ./rep_a.dump
svndumpfilter include trunk/project/subproject --drop-empty-revs --renumber-revs --preserve-revprops < ./rep_a.dump > ./rep_a_filtered.dump
svnadmin load my_repositories/rep_b < ./rep_a_filtered.dump
```

However, the last command fails with this message:

```
<<<< Started new transaction, based on original revision 1
      * adding path : trunk/project/subproject ...svnadmin: File not found: transaction
      '3-a', path 'trunk/project/subproject'
```

That error message is rather criptic to me. Any idea what it means ?

I thought perhaps it means that it's looking for a trunk/project/subproject in rep_b
so I tried added them manually (i.e. via a add/commit) and then tried the same command again. This doesn't work either and gives me this:

```
File already exists: filesystem 'rep_b\db', transaction....
```

any clues ? what am I doing wrong here ?

David

Comment: Were there any revisions in your repository that affected files both inside and outside trunk/project/subproject? If so, you may have trouble.

Comment: Was the trunk/project/subproject directory in rep_a created by copying another directory?

Comment: @ Omnifarious, I'm not sure I understand what you mean with "created by copying another dir". They are just a bunch of files under revision control...

Comment: @Avi, what do you mean revisions affecting files inside and outside of the dir ? it's an svn repository, so of course there are files inside and outside of trunk/project/subproject that are modified. I guess I didn't get your point...

Comment: I mean files outside the trunk/project/subproject path. If one commit affected files in subproject, but also in another project, it would be a problem for the dumpfilter to either filter out that commit or leave it in.

Comment: @Avi, ah! there are definitely commits that affected files both in and out of trunk/project/subproject (bad practice I guess)... does that mean I have to live with no having the hitory 'ported' to the new rep ? -- sorry for such late follow-up, just returned from holidays

Comment: I guess it might theoretically be possible to program something that would do it for you, but it would be difficult. I would probably go with 'losing' the history (of course, the older history will always be available in the old repository, and pretty soon you won't really need it any more, at least most of the time).

Comment: You should try to think pretty carefully about your repository organization, so that you don't run into this problem. That may mean keeping all projects in one repository (this works pretty well, in practice), and/or making sure that commits are local to a project, and code isn't moved between projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see Avi's comments on the question for answer

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind losing the history from the first repo, just apply the following command to your checked out repo1 tree :

```
find <repo1> -name ".svn" | xargs rm -rf
```

This will remove all .svn files from all directories in the checked out tree and avoid the second error.

Of course this is assuming you are using cygwin / unix.

Cheers

Comment: Clearly, the poster is trying to move the directory, along with its SVN history, otherwise he could have just exported from the first repo, and imported into the second.

Comment: keeping the history is why I'm going through this... otherwise, I could just copy the stuff in the new repository and do a normal add/commit.

Comment: by the way you can use 'svn export' to copy a working copy without the all the .svn