# Subversion - Move folder to another already existing repository

Tags: svn, repository, svnadmin, svndumpfilter

I have the following SVN structure:

- ExistingRepository1

  - ...
  - MyFolder

    - FolderToMove
    - ...
- ExistingRepository2

  - ...
  - AnotherFolder

    - FolderToMove <- moved here
    - ...

So I already read this question: [How do I move a single folder from one Subversion repository to another repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417726/how-to-move-a-single-folder-from-one-subversion-repository-to-another-repository)
But in my case ExistingRepository2 already exists.
So how can I do it? I want to have all revisions in the new project.

I have for example the revision number 1000 in `ExistingRepository1 -> MyFolder -> FolderToMove`, but in the `ExistingRepository1`there is already a revision with number 1000. So, what will the `svn load` do? Will it automatically move the revision numbers?

These would be the commands:

```
svnadmin dump /svn/ExistingRepository1 > ./repository.dump
svndumpfilter include MyFolder/FolderToMove --drop-empty-revs --renumber-revs --preserve-revprops < ./repository.dump > ./folderToMove_only.dump
svnadmin load /svn/ExistingRepository2 < ./folderToMove_only.dump
```

Thank you in advance for your help, Best Regards, Tim.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Here](http://nileshbansal.blogspot.com/2006/03/moving-folder-across-svn-repositories.html) is somebody who claims to have moved a directory across existing repositories (with some blog comments that indicate success).  Apparently it creates the whole path in the destination repository, but I imagine that once the directory is in the destination repository you can easily move it to where you want it (while maintaining its history).

**[Edit]**

I successfully tested this.  Here are the commands I used:

```
svnadmin dump /path/to/source/repo | svndumpfilter --drop-empty-revs --renumber-revs include /folder/to/transfer/ > dumpfile
svnadmin load /path/to/destination/repo < dumpfile
```

I then moved the transferred file (using TortoiseSVN's Repo-browser).