# How do I move a portion of a subversion repository to a new one without losing the history?

Tags: svn, migration, repository

I have a subversion repository which currently has code, documentation and deliverables. This is becoming messy and unmanageable so I'd like to split the repositories into three.

How can I move subsections of the original repository (which will contain purely code) into new `Documentation` and `Deliverables` repositories without losing the history? For example:

```
<old_repos>\Docs
<old_repos>\Deliverables
<old_repos>\Src
```

...becomes:

```
<docs_repos>
<deliverables_repos>
<src_repos>
```

I've seen a lot of posts about moving folders around within a repository and others showing how to move one whole repository to another, but nothing that suggests how to just move a subset. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [svndumpfilter](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.reposadmin.maint.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.filtering). There's instructions in the docs there, although

- you can't (last time I tried) use a `--deltas` dump - it doesn't support that. I think `--incremental` was OK though
- editing the paths on all files usually means carefully editing the dump file, which is a pain because it's a mix of binary and text. I normally have to delete the first few revisions that create directories and amend one of them to make the correct new directories too.

It takes a bit of effort but I've done this successfully a few times.

Answer (score 1):

**Not tried and not tested personally**

You'll use svnadmin dump, svnadmin load and svndumpfilter (commands are slightly Unixish-style)

1 Create full dump of original repo: `svnadmin dump . > full.dump`

2-4 Filter dump and leave only revisions, related to needed subdir respectivey: `cat full.dump | svndumpfilter include DIR-PATH --drop-empty-revs  --renumber-revs --skip-missing-merge-sources --preserve-revprops > DIR-PATH.dump`

5-7 For every new empty repo: `svnadmin load . --parent-dir trunk --ignore-uuid < DIR-PATH.dmp`

In worst case new repos will get not `/trunk/*.* data-trees`, but `/trunk/DIR-PATH/*.*`, which are easy eliminated by one big move and delete empty DIR-PATH after all

PS - I just discovered after writing my text: [How to move a single folder from one Subversion repository to another repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417726/how-to-move-a-single-folder-from-one-subversion-repository-to-another-repository)