# Need to put existing subversion project under a new root folder

Tags: svn, subclipse

I am trying to get subversion to play nice with my new maven setup

Consider the following sscce scenario:

**Project 1** - Already in SVN

```
/project1
  /src
  /target
  pom.xml
```

**Project 2** - Also already in SVN

```
/project2
  /src
  /target
  pom.xml
```

I want to transform both of these projects to be modules of one, global maven project, i.e.

```
/myProjects
  /project1
    /src
    /target
    pom.xml
  /project2
    /src
    /target
    pom.xml
  pom.xml
```

The file systems are already set up in exactly this way on both the server and my development machine, but the outer `/myProjects` isn't an actual subversion folder (I created it using "Rightclick -> New -> New Remote Folder" in subclipse, then "Rightclick -> Rename/Move" on the other folders. But then I tried to do "myProjects -> Share Project" and it wanted to purge my SVN data/comments etc.

What should I do? Is [this direct command solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417726/how-to-move-a-single-folder-from-one-subversion-repository-to-another-repository) the only way, or can I do it using subclipse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. There *are not* such thing, as "Subversion project" (or at least it's *disambiguation*). Are /project1 and /project2 roots of **separate Subversion repositories** or are they **different paths in common repository**?
2. In any case, some type of access to repositories server (and admin-side tools) is needed, subclipse is only client-side subversion client

   - Dump/Load way is usable common way for **physical joining** of two (or more) independent repositories
   - You can also select and implement **logical joining** of repositories: create new repository with /myProjects in the root, add /project1 and /project2 as directory-externals and get needed logical tree from three physical repositories
   - If /project1 and /project2 are parts of common repo, your can reorganize repository-tree, using only client-side commands: `svn mkdir`+`svn mv` will do the trick

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. They are in the same repo, different paths. I moved them (using Subclipse) probably exactly the same as `svn mkdir` and `svn mv` would do, but the problem is when I try to do "Team -> Share Project" in `myProject`it gives me a warning that it's going to delete all the subversion files because the subprojects in eclipse are linked independently.

Comment: @durron597 - sorry, Eclipse specifics isn't my theme