# Creating a new SVN repository from an existing branch

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, visualsvn-server

I have a branch in one of my SVN repositories that I would like to copy into the trunk of a new repository I just created. Preferably I would like to retain all of the history from this branch. I thought about checking out the branch, disconnecting it from SVN, and then copying all of the files into my new repository trunk, but that seems a little sloppy and I'd like to find a better way. Preferably I would like to do this using Visual SVN Server or Tortoise SVN rather than command line.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/417726/how-do-i-move-a-single-folder-from-one-subversion-repository-to-another-reposito

Comment: @nos thank you, but honestly I am not comfortable running a big command like that when I don't understand what it's even doing. I will read more on this post though